# WCF base address

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a wcf service that **was** accessible via http or https. It runs in a shared hosting environment.

I cancelled the SSL hosting. i.e. The private IP for SSL was removed, etc.

I did not make any changes to my config.

Now, if I simply try to access my service like

http://myservice.com/myservice.svc?wsdl

I get the following error:

**Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].**

Notice the error message mentions a scheme of **https**. Not sure why.

Any help on any of this?

**UPDATE with Config Info:**

```
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://mysite.com/"/>
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MySiteServiceBehavior" name="MySite.MyService">
    <clear/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MySiteBasicBinding" name="MySiteBasicEndpoint"
      contract="MySite.IMyService"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MySiteBasicSslBinding" name="MySiteBasicSslEndpoint"
      contract="MySite.IMyService"/>
    <endpoint address="json" endpointConfiguration="myJson" kind="webHttpEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MySiteBasicBinding"
      name="jsonEndpoint" contract="MySite.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="MySite.MyServiceBehavior.json"/>
    <endpoint address="json" endpointConfiguration="myJson" kind="webHttpEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MySiteBasicSslBinding"
      name="jsonSslEndpoint" contract="MySite.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="MySite.MyServiceBehavior.json"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://MySite.com/MyService.svc"/>
        <add baseAddress="https://MySite.com/MyService.svc"/> **--- still have problem with this line commented out**
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MySiteBasicBinding"/>
    <binding name="MySiteBasicSslBinding">
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MySiteBasicBinding"/>
    <binding name="MySiteBasicSslBinding">
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MySiteServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/> **--- still have problem with httpsGetEnabled set to false**
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MySite.MyServiceBehavior.json">
      <!--<enableWebScript/>-->
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="myJson" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

UPDATE

I removed any/all references even remotely related to https and it worked.
I am just surprised that was required.

Comment: please add the service configuration to your question

Comment: Show some effort, did you look in the config for a reference to HTTPS?

Comment: Read the answer you have httpsGetEnabled.  Did you try removing https from the config?

Comment: It is only after I remove numerous config elements that I can make it work. Thanks, Blam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you still have httpsGetEnabled on your behavior element in serviceBehaviors.

Comment: Removing numerous references to https related items solved the problem.